# SuperPanel for Flex 4 (Drag, Resize, Close, Maximize, Minimize)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, custom-component

I found this component on the internet (http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/files/flex/SuperPanel/v1_5/MainView.html) and those panels are just great. Unfortunately, that source-code doesn't suit well on Flex 4. Spark components works differently on changing their structure (adding buttons to the padding top, etc) and working with the MX components doesn't work properly the Drag function and it looks ugly.
I'd like to know if anyone have a link for a similar component already done in Flex 4 or any path that I could take to be able to build it myself.
I have plenty of experience with ActionScript, but almost none with CSS/Styling on Flex or Flex 4.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the MDI component that is part of [flexlib](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib)?